# Reduced form of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Let's look at the following sentence.

I don't like barking dogs. Here 'barking' is an adjective called perticipial adjective. The sentence is a reduced form of ' I don't like dogs that bark'. 
So a present perticiple form can be used as an adjective.

Now let's look at the sentence.

People curse on the oppressing king. 
Is the word 'oppressing'  an adjective here. Is it correct to use here. Though we can use here 'oppressive' instead of 'oppressing'.

If the sentence is correct it should be a reduced form of 'People curse on the king that oppresses'. 
Does it make sense?

Comment: What has this got to do with reduced forms?

Comment: It's best to keep form and function separate. *Barking* and *oppressing* are not adjectives. You can't inflect them for comparison, for one. One dog is not barkinger than another. These words are verbs, specifically participles, which can function as noun modifiers like adjectives. *Oppress* is a transitive verb, so its forms can take **objects** like "oppressing **people**," but this means the people are oppressed although this has the same sequence as "oppressing king." Thus the handy word *oppressive*.

Comment: Also, you put a curse on people or you curse them directly.

Comment: “I don’t like barking dogs” could also mean “I don’t like any dogs for the duration that they are barking” - I might be fine with the same dog when it’s *not* barking. That’s not *quite* the same as “I don’t like dogs that bark” - to my mind that implies you don’t like those particular dogs at all, whether they are barking right now or not.